# How can I bulk insert test data into a table in postgresql or cockroachdb?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cockroachdb

In procedural SQL, I could write a loop that used an incrementing variable to build data rows and insert them into a table one by one. Is there a way to get the same effect using the regular SQL syntax supported by CockroachDB? I don't want to have to programatically build a

```sql
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( ... )
```

statement, or run many inserts in a loop outside of database code.

Answer (score 0):

There's some nice syntax for this! You can write

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename(<column list>) SELECT <expr> FROM generate_series(1,<n>) i;
```

`generate_series(start, end) i` can be selected from as though it were a table with a single column, i, with rows valued from start to end. You can use this to build a tuple that lines up with the columns you're populating, and insert all the results at once. For example,

```sql
INSERT INTO foo(id, name, data) SELECT i, 'name'||i, random() FROM generate_series(1,1000) i;
```

Will insert 1000 rows with ids 1-1000, names that look like "name632", and random floats in the data column.